# Pass string from C# to C DLL

Tags: c#, c, string, dll, char

I am trying to pass a string from C# to a C DLL. From what I have read .NET should do the conversion from string to char* for me, however I get "error CS1503: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char*'" Can someone advise me of where I have went wrong? Thanks.

C# code

```
[DllImport("Source.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static unsafe extern bool StreamReceiveInitialise(char* filepath);

const string test = "test";
// This method that will be called when the thread is started
public void Stream()
{
    if (StreamReceiveInitialise(test))
    {


    }
}
```

C DLL

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) bool __cdecl StreamReceiveInitialise(char* filepath);
}
```

Comment: Why declare StreamReceiveInitialise as unsafe? Now you still need to pass a char* instead of a string.

Comment: I have now removed unsafe and am using as shown in answer 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your external method as:

```
public static extern bool StreamReceiveInitialise(string filepath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
[DllImport("Source.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.ANSI)]
static extern bool StreamReceiveInitialise([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filepath);
```

(Marshalling as UnmanagedType.LPStr is the default, but I like being explicit).

Comment: That [MarshalAs] attribute is unnecessary, it is already the default marshaling for the string in this case.

Comment: But specifying the `CharSet` on the `DllImport` attribute wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: I should have mentioned I do not need modify filepath within the C code. Does this change your comments? Apologies I am new to mixing C/C#.

Comment: CharSet.ANSI is default, but I agree that it should be specified to be explicit.

Comment: I have specfified CharSet.ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder in place of char*.   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994477/c-sharp-pinvoke-out-strings-declaration)

```
[DllImport("Source.dll")]
public static extern bool StreamReceiveInitialise(StringBuilder filepath);
```